# How to receive id in table cell from datatables serverside processing?

Tags: php, codeigniter, datatables

I working on `codeigniter` **datatables serverside processing**. I receive data into `view` from controller with `datatables serverside processing`. The question is how to receive id in table cell `<td id="id_here">some cell data</td>`

My datatables serverside code is:

```
foreach($fetch_data as $row)  
            {  

                 $sub_array = array();  

                $sub_array[] = $no++;



                $sub_array[] = $row->semester;
                $sub_array[] = $row->name;
                $sub_array[] = $row->quiz_marks;
                $data[] = $sub_array;  
            }  
            $output = array(  
                 "draw"                    =>     intval($_POST["draw"]),  
                 "recordsTotal"          =>      $this->Activity_model->get_all_data_exams(),  
                 "recordsFiltered"     =>     $this->Activity_model->get_filtered_data_exams(),  
                 "data"                    =>     $data  
            );  
            echo json_encode($output);
```

On view i recive data in `table` like this.

```
<tr>
  <td>1st</td>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td>10</td>
</tr>
```

I need `table` data with `id`

***like this***

```
<tr>
  <td id="32">1st</td>
  <td id="32">Mark</td>
  <td id="32">10</td>
</tr>
```

my view code is:

```
<table id="dt-basic-example" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped w-100">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>Program</th>
            <th>Semester</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Quiz</th>
            <th>Presentation</th>
            <th>Assigment</th>
            <th>Sessional</th>
            <th>Mid</th>
            <th>Fianl</th>
            <th>Total</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>


    </tbody>

</table>

<script>
$('#dt-basic-example').dataTable(
{

"processing":true,
"serverSide":true,
"order":[],
"ajax":{
url:"<?php echo base_url() . 'ExamsLoadBs'; ?>",
type:"POST"
},  });
</script>
```

Comment: where do you generate `<td></td>` ?

Comment: dear its come from server side beacuse i use ajax datatables

Comment: first of all - multiple ids with the same name are not html compliant, the second point is - datatables doesn't add id values to its specific rows / cells and the third question is - why do you even need this ?

Comment: Dear i want when i clicked on particular cell it  be change into input field. Then i enter some data inside it, then this data will be automatically updated into database through ajax.

Comment: Thanks dear i gotit the solution. I'll use javascript for this purpose.

Comment: `$sub_array[] = "<span data-edit  class='program' id='".$row->id."'>".$row->program."</span>";`

Comment: `$('body').on('click', '[data-edit]', function(){
           var $el = $(this);
            var $input = $('<input />').val( $el.text() );
        $el.replaceWith( $input );
          var save = function(){
            var $p = $('<span data-edit ></span>').text( $input.val() );
            $input.replaceWith( $p );
            var value=$input.val();
            var id= $el.attr('id') ;
            var field_name= $el.attr('class') ;
            console.log(value + id + field_name);
  };

  $input.one('blur', save).focus();
});`